# Failed to execute aapt for codenameone androild build

Tags: codenameone

Am getting Failed to execute aapt for codenameone androild build. This was working perfectly some few hours ago and now am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

We [moved to Android API level 30](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-api-level-30.html) today and as a result some builds for some users experienced problems. This was just resolved on the serves and ideally should work now. If it doesn't we'll need the full error log.